# Accessing documentation on c++

Tags: c++

I'm a novice programmer who just migrated from Python (on IDLE) to C++ and I'm finding it uncomfortable to know only a few "essential" methods of STL data structures. Is there something like the Python help() function in C++, or some other way to access digestible and concise documentation as regards the Standard Library?

Edit: To be clear, I am looking for a way to access documentation from my computer, preferably from within the IDE/compiler (I currently use and prefer g++ on Cygwin in Windows 7. I also have Code::Blocks, however). Please don't recommend books or mark this question as a duplicate of The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List.

Answer (score 8):

This is the documentation  I like the most : http://en.cppreference.com/w/

With a keyword for fast searching in Firefox, it is very efficient

Answer (score 0):

http://cppreference.com

http://www.cplusplus.com

If you're on Mac OS, you can use the nice [Dash](http://kapeli.com/dash) which can integrate with editors or be used on its own. It supports the cppreference.com docs (instant offline indexed documentation).

If you're on Windows (Visual Studio) MSDN also provides STL docs.

As I'm on Linux I just use http://cppreference.com, but I'd like to have a good alternative (not Zeal) to Dash.

Answer (score 0):

- In general [Cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com) helps very much.
- Maybe the [GNU C++
  Library](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/) will also help.
- You could also read the official C++
  book by Bjarne Stroustrup.